# Unable to configure Homestead per-project with Laravel 6 on PHP <7.1

Tags: composer-php, vagrant, homestead, laravel-6

I'm setting up a Laravel 6 project to use Homestead per-project, but running into a Catch-22 when cloning the repo on a machine without PHP 7.2 installed locally.

The issue is that Laravel 6 requires PHP 7.2 (I have 7.1 installed locally), which means `composer update` will not work locally:

```
This package requires php ^7.2 but your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement.
```

which means I cannot `vagrant up` to get to the Homestead box (that includes PHP 7.2) without having run `composer update`:

```
Message: LoadError: cannot load such file -- /Users/.../.../vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb
```

which means I cannot get anything working.

To get around this, I either have to a) upgrade my local machine to PHP 7.2 to be able to run `composer update` or b) install Homestead separately and run `vagrant up` from there, both of which bypass the benefit of a per-project set up.

Is there something I'm missing to get this configuration to work?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to install multiple versions of php and then set your default version like this `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1`?

Comment: @Leif_Lundberg I'm creating this Homestead environment for a development team who use a decent cross section of OSes and may or may not have PHP 7.2 installed. I want them to all be able to clone the repo and jump into their vagrant boxes without a bunch of local configuration.

Comment: @Travis Have you found the solution yet ? Facing similar issue - I want to use per project homestead with Laravel 8. However my host is still php7 which makes it impossible to install Laravel 8 that needs php8. I could upgrade the php version or have a global homestead. But that kinda takes away the fun/purpose of per project Homestead. Please share if you have got this figured out, thank you!